# W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/partner i386 Packages

Tags: updates, repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I fix the GPG error “NO_PUBKEY”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Whenever I try to download package information from all configured sources using

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get:

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures could not be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0
(/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_partner_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that this public key has not been added.

Get the Public Key. Which in your case is 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0

Now add it, by typing this command in terminal

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0
```

Now update it:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Source: http://maketecheasier.com/fix-ubuntu-update-errors/2011/12/16

Comment: that is only part of the answer, he has a confliction of repositories also natty/oneiric

Comment: OP what are you currently using? natty or oneiric?